# Has there ever been a season where all the races were won by a single team?

Tags: formula-1

In 2014, there were 19 races and 16 of them were won by Mercedes. Has there ever been a season where one team won all the races?

Answer (score 5):

No. This has never happened. There have, however, been four occasions in which a team won every race except one:

- In 1950, Alfa Romeo won 6 of the 7 races, but did not enter the Indy 500 (which was part of the championship in those days).
- In 1952, Ferrari won 7 of the 8 races. They *did* enter the Indy 500, but Alberto Ascari retired after one of his car's wheel hubs collapsed.
- In 1988, McLaren won 15 of the 16 races, and came within two laps of winning the other (the Italian Grand Prix) only for Jean-Louis Schlesser to collide with Ayrton Senna and take him out of the race.
- In 2023, Red Bull won 21 of the 22 races, but failed to win the Singapore Grand Prix as their car wasn't suited to the track.

Ferrari in 1953 and 2002, and Mercedes in 1955 and 2016, were the next-closest, winning all but two of the races in those seasons.

Answer (score 0):

A team has won every grand prix in a season, 1952 Ferrari. They didn't win every race of the season as the Indy 500 have World championship points even though it was not a grand prix. It is the closest argument for a team winning every, official, race of a season.

Comment: The Indy 500 *was* an "official" race in 1952, even if it wasn't a grand prix. Its presence in the championship until 1960 throws up a lot of statistical anomalies but it's still counted in the record books and shouldn't be arbitrarily discarded.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. Can you add a source to your answer?

Comment: It's not arbitrarily discarded, it was impossible to do the Swiss Grand prix and indy 500 as qualifying (although it was rained off) for the Indy and the Swiss Grand Prix were both on the 18th May, points were awarded for Indy because of its status.